# How to maintain or reestablish connection between content and background after tabs update in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have made a long time connection between content.js and background.js, like [chrome documents about message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging). I use a  "chrome.tabs.update" step. After it, I want to send a message from background to content. It always gives an error: "Error in event handler: Error: Attempting to use a disconnected port object". Does it means that when the tab reloads, all the things including the port are deleted? Is there a way to maintain or establish the connection? 
Thank you for any suggestion.

content.js

```
var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: "knockknock"});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if( request.message === "clicked_browser_action" ) {
            port.postMessage({joke: "Knock knock",key: "aaa"});     
        }
    }
);

port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
    if (msg.question == "Knock knock success!"){
        console.log(msg.question);
        var url0 = window.location.toString();
        port.postMessage({joke: "url",key: url0});
    }
    else if (msg.question == "Next"){
    }

})
```

background.js

```
var tabId;
var url_search = "https://www.youtube.com/";

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    var activeTab = tabs[0];
    tabId = activeTab.id;
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {"message": "clicked_browser_action"});
  });
});

chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
    console.assert(port.name == "knockknock");
    port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
        if (msg.joke == "Knock knock"){
            port.postMessage({question: "Knock knock success!"});
        }
        else if(msg.joke == "url"){
            chrome.tabs.update(tabId,{url: url_search});
            chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tab , info) {
                if(info.status === 'complete' && tab == tabId ){
                    port.postMessage({joke: "Next",key: "bbb"});// This line trigger the error!
                }
            })
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Yes, the content scripts are part of the page environment so when the tab loads a different page all the old stuff gets removed including the content scripts and their objects, ports, everything. If you have content_scripts in manifest.json then a new fresh instance of the content script runs in the new URL. You may want to use the [simple one-time messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#simple) instead of port messaging.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you. I will use one-time message instead. But the one-time message always give an error "The message port closed before a response was received" in the console.log, even though the extension seems work well.  I don't know how to avoid it. I make an example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57085797/how-to-fix-unchecked-runtime-lasterror-the-message-port-closed-before-a-respon