# How to fix "Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received." in self made chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am doing some simple tests to using one time communication between content and background.js. The code is below. I always found the error "Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received." occur in my console.log. In the below script, I made 2 step.

Step 1. give a message from background to content as soon as the browser action.
Step 2. send a message back from content to background. If background received the message, it alerts.

I think the error would be triggered when the message is only send without received. But in my script, the two message are both received. Why the error still happened? I am very confused about it. I will be very thankful if anyone could tell me the reason or how to fix this.

I also did some tests. The error seems happened related to the message from content to background. Should I close or clear the port manually in the script?

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if( request.message === "clicked_browser_action" ) {
            console.log('content initial');
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({joke: "Knock knock",key:"initial from content"}, function(response) {
            });
        }
    }
);
```

background.js

```
//initial 
var tabId;
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    var activeTab = tabs[0];
    tabId = activeTab.id;
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {"message": "clicked_browser_action"});
  });
});

//receive
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.joke == "Knock knock"){
            alert(request.key);
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Use sendResponse inside onMessage of the content script as shown in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#simple) and a callback instead of popup's onMessage as shown in the same example.

Comment: @wOxxOm Do you mean that I should use "chrome.tabs.sendMessage" inside a listener "chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener"?

Comment: I said the opposite of that. See the example in the documentation I've linked.